# How do you add a button which opens a page in a pop-up window

Tags: html

I am working on a PHP file upload, but I want the button which opens my uploading page to open it in an pop up window. So it would be like many sites do it, press a button and It opens a pop up where you can upload files.

Here is a code that I tried and it didn't work:

```html
<a href="upload.html" target="_blank">
<input type="button" class="button" value="Upload" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use type=file

```html
<a href="upload.html" target="_blank">
<input type="file" class="button" value="Upload" />
```

Comment: I was actually talking about the button that opens the page but nvm.

Answer (score 0):

see link-- https://jsfiddle.net/mu3ju64c/1/

```html
<input type="button" value="Open a Popup Window" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/javascript/examples/sample_popup.cfm','popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');">

  <p> ----------------------according to your code----------------- </p>
<a href="upload.html" target="_blank">
<input type="file" class="button" value="Upload" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the input type="file".
Example: input type="file" name="myFile"

If you want to style/change the default button you can by doing so...
read this> [custom file upload button](https://blog.benestudio.co/custom-file-upload-button-with-pure-css-5aacf39aa0a)

Also close your a tag if your still going to do it that way.